# How can i override method and check permission on my CrudController?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm using Backpack version 4.1

I want to override the index() method on this trait

```
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
```

because I want to check permission before proceeding.

I can't do it like this(code below) because this method didn't inherit from another class

```
public function index()
{
   // my check permisison here

   return parent::index();
}
```

This works but I don't like it because I don't want to stop receiving updates from backpack

```
    public function index()
    {
        abort_unless(
            auth()->user()->can('tag_view'), 403
        );

        $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('list');

        $this->data['crud'] = $this->crud;
        $this->data['title'] = $this->crud->getTitle() ?? mb_ucfirst($this->crud->entity_name_plural);

        // load the view from /resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/ if it exists, otherwise load the one in the package
        return view($this->crud->getListView(), $this->data);
    }
```

This is the original index method trait.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('list');

        $this->data['crud'] = $this->crud;
        $this->data['title'] = $this->crud->getTitle() ?? mb_ucfirst($this->crud->entity_name_plural);

        // load the view from /resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/ if it exists, otherwise load the one in the package
        return view($this->crud->getListView(), $this->data);
    }
```

what I want is like this but doesn't work because the index method return view();

```
public function index()
{
  // do my permission here or etc
  return $this->index();
}
```

How can I perform permission checks on my CrudController? like: index, update, edit, delete

Please excuse my ignorance because Im new to Backpack and laravel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking Spatie Permissions to Backpack UI show/hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63395129/linking-spatie-permissions-to-backpack-ui-show-hide)

Comment: Please see my answer for the similar question above. main take away is that your setup or setupXOpperation method should call `$this->crud->allowAccess($action);` or `$this->crud->denyAccess($action);`. In my apps I use the Spatie permissions app to define and assign permissions and in my example I check for those permissions and either allow or deny access based on the result. Note that the code uses laravels built in `Gate::check($requiredPermission)` so you could use anything compatible with laravel's [authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization) system for the actual perms

Comment: thanks, Wesley i got an idea base on your answers. thanks so much.